# why does the origin move?

Tags: modeling, transforms

while making a character(but obviously with any mesh primitives as well), after the scale was applied, the origin of the character moves? why does blender does this? Is this just a bug or is there any logical explanation for this?
Here is the sample image showing the problem due to which rigging is taking a difficult step(my version of blender is 2.70):
[image]

Comment: Do you have to apply the scale multiple times? If not you can just move the cursor to the original origin and then after the apply move origin to 3D cursor (found in the toolbar). This is just a work around

Comment: I don't get this, I can't replicate. Can you show an example image?

Comment: I edited my question and posted the sample image above.

Comment: You applied all the transforms, including location, which makes [current location of the object to be 0,0,0](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=applying%20transforms#apply-options). Does the origin move when you apply *only* scale ? (`Ctrl`+`A` > *Scale*)

Comment: No, actually it doesn't. But when I took a rigging tutorial , it was said that the location has to be applied to generate rigify properly, but how can I do that when the origin keeps moving away? The generated armature doesn't fit properly to the mesh character.

Comment: Move the mesh to the scene center, so 0,0,0. The easiest way to do that is by [*clearing* object location](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=applying%20transforms#clear-options).

Comment: but that would mean the eyes and inner objects would also move to the origin, and if they were seperate meshes the whole would distort. Is there an alternative option?

Comment: The whole mesh shouldn't distort if you select everything together with armature and move. However I'm afraid this process should've been done before as it may be quite complex to repair it now (without deleting armature). Read more [in this tutorial](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/character-6-armature-rigging.php)